# how to make a boot-able backup on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: backup

The backup should not contain any personal data only the OS and packages installed.

Comment: what is the purpose of the backup if it shouldn't contain any personal data?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create backup of your Ubuntu and make a live CD or create an iso file of your backup and make a bootable USB or CD and install it anywhere. You can get help creating backup from [Creating Custom Ubuntu Live CD With Remastersys](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/creating-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-with-remastersys.html) and make an iso by right-click on file compress and select '.zip.' to '.iso' from dropdown list on righthand side there.
2. Create  an ISO (use UNetbootin).
3. Install it wherever you want.

Comment: create backup of your ubuntu and make live cd or create iso file of your backup and make bootable usb or cd and install it anywhere. you can get help creating backup from the following link and make iso by right click on file compress and select '.zip. to '.iso' from  dropdown list on right hand side there.  http://www.ubuntugeek.com/creating-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-with-remastersys.html

Comment: When I edited your answer I noticed that your link from 2008 (more than 9 years ago) is obsolete. Remastersys tool was abandoned years ago. Pinguy Builder, mentioned in Katu's answer, is a fork of the Remastersys tool which was abandoned years ago, but updating your link that way will make your answer into a duplicate of Katu's answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Pinguy Builder](http://pinguyos.com/2015/09/pinguy-builder-an-app-to-backupremix-buntu/http://pinguyos.com/2015/09/pinguy-builder-an-app-to-backupremix-buntu/) does that.

> The Pinguy Builder will create a installable ISO of your current system. You can then burn that ISO to a USB using something like Unetbootin or just burn the ISO directly to a DVD. The DVD/USB can then be booted from a PC.
>
> Depending on what option you choose determines what type of ISO gets created.
>   If you pick “Dist”, this will backup the whole system but exclude your home folder and any personal info.
>
> If you pick “Backup”, this will backup the system and will include you home folder (so make sure it isn’t to big).
>
> Both options can run as a live session. “Dist” mode has no password to login. “Backup” mode uses the user name and password used to create the ISO.

You can download it from sourceforge: [Pinguy OS ISO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/)

And install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i pinguybuilder_4.3-8_all-beta.deb
```

After the installation, you can use it from the command line with

```
sudo PinguyBuilder backup|clean|dist [cdfs|iso] [filename.iso]
```

Or with the GUI, which has buttons to complete all the available actions.

```
PinguyBuilder-gtk
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/714816)

Comment: @Anwar thanks for the comment. Unfortunately this answer depends on the link and pinguy builder tool being available to download. I have added more information about the tool to complete the answer.

Comment: Where do I download it and how do I use it?

Comment: @Anwar I see what you mean... updated.