# building ubuntu-keyring for custom ISO

Tags: 17.10, iso, gnupg, keyrings

I have been unable to find clear instructions on building a customized Ubuntu ISO.  Many sources say that I must first generate a custom build of `ubuntu-keyring` which I will use to verify the packages on the ISO.  But none of the instructions I've found for making a custom build have actually worked.

Examples: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization#Generating_a_new_ubuntu-keyring_.deb_to_sign_your_CD
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization/Scripts

So far, this is what seems to be working, but I really have no way to tell if I'm doing this much correct:

```
apt-get source ubuntu-keyring
cd ubuntu-keyring-*/keyrings

cat >gpg.gen <<GEN
%no-protection
Key-Type: DSA
Key-Length: 1024
Subkey-Type: ELG-E
Subkey-Length: 1024
Name-Real: Rich Remer
Name-Email: rich.remer@example.com
Expire-Date: 0
%pubring my.gpg
%commit
GEN

gpg --batch --gen-key gpg.gen
gpg --import < my.gpg 2>/dev/null
gpg --import < ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg 2>/dev/null

my=$(gpg my.gpg | grep -A1 ^pub | grep ^\\s)
ubuntu=$(gpg ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg | grep -A1 ^pub | grep ^\\s)
keys="$my $ubuntu"

gpg --yes --output=ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg --export $keys

cd ..    # into ubuntu-keyring source directory
```

At this point, I attempt to use the following recommended command to rebuild the package with my key:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -m"Rich Remer <rich.remer@example.com>" -k$key
```

This results in a build error:

```
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package ubuntu-keyring
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 2016.10.27
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution zesty
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build ubuntu-keyring-2016.10.27
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
test -f keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
rm -f foo foo.asc *.bak *~ */*~ debian/files* debian/*substvars
rm -rf debian/tmp debian/ubuntu-keyring-udeb
 dpkg-source -b ubuntu-keyring-2016.10.27
dpkg-source: warning: no source format specified in debian/source/format, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: info: using source format '1.0'
dpkg-source: info: building ubuntu-keyring in ubuntu-keyring_2016.10.27.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building ubuntu-keyring in ubuntu-keyring_2016.10.27.dsc
 debian/rules build
make: Nothing to be done for 'build'.
 fakeroot debian/rules binary
test -f keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
test root = "`whoami`"
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/debian-keyring.gpg --decrypt SHA512SUMS.txt.asc | sha512sum -c -
keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg: FAILED
gpg: Signature made Thu 27 Oct 2016 07:31:05 AM PDT
gpg:                using RSA key CAC2D8B9CD2CA5F9
keyrings/ubuntu-archive-removed-keys.gpg: OK
keyrings/ubuntu-keyring-2012-archive.gpg: OK
keyrings/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg: OK
keyrings/ubuntu-master-keyring.gpg: OK
gpg: Good signature from "Dimitri John Ledkov <xnox@ubuntu.com>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Dimitri John Ledkov <xnox@debian.org>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Dimitri John Ledkov (Member, Board of Directors) <xnox@spi-inc.org>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Dimitri John Ledkov (2015) <dimitri.ledkov@canonical.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: D764 F6CC 2AB5 9A38 B114  7D73 887B 6061 8B3C 16AE
     Subkey fingerprint: 773C 99EB D0A1 1172 217A  7C3F CAC2 D8B9 CD2C A5F9
sha512sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
debian/rules:88: recipe for target 'checkkeyrings' failed
make: *** [checkkeyrings] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

I'm not sure what else I should be doing to get the `ubuntu-keyring` package to build.  This must be performed unattended with no user interaction, if that's important.  One thing I noticed is I'm running Artful Aardvark, but the build is reporting: `info: source distribution zesty`.  Could be a red herring, or it might be important.

Comment: Can you link to one of these sources asking you to create a modified `ubuntu-keyring` package?

Comment: I've added links.

Comment: Hmm, that would apply if you need to add packages from outside Ubuntu repos. As long as the packages you install in the custom ISO come from Ubuntu, you don't need to do it. So which are you doing?

Comment: I am installing additional packages that are not part of the ISO, but they are pulled from the standard repos.  So, you're saying just skip this step?

Comment: When I run the installer, the packages are still being downloaded.  I assumed it was because of the ubuntu-keyring signature, but perhaps the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: you can skip this if all packages are from the standard repos. When you run the installer, did you check the download updates option?

Comment: Another approach to create a custom distro may be helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/910674/how-to-make-a-boot-able-backup-on-ubuntu-17-04/910686#910686

Comment: I'm running the installer unattended, so I'm not sure if "download updates" is active, but I'll take a look and see how that is configured.

Comment: Pinguy looks interesting, but unfortunately doesn't suit my purposes.  From what I can tell, you need a system already setup, but I'm trying to bootstrap system setup from scratch.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
cat ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg | sha512sum
```

copy and replace in:
in ubuntu-keyring-*/SHA512SUMS.txt.asc before "keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg"